# Pandas Groupby, Sum, and Flatten Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe where I want to `groupby` a couple conditions and then sum a few fields. When I sum the values I want to flatten the values

With an input of:

```
UserID    Site    First Name    Last Name    May Hours    June Hours     July Hours
6385         A          John          Doe            8             9             10
6385         A          John          Doe            3             7              8
4756         A          Mark         Mean            7             6              5
4756         B          Mark         Mean            3             2              3
```

and grouping by `UserID` and `Site`, I want an output of:

```
UserID    Site    First Name    Last Name    May Hours    June Hours     July Hours
6385         A          John          Doe           11            16             18
4756         A          Mark         Mean            7             6              5
4756         B          Mark         Mean            3             2              3
```

It can be assumed that besides the UserID, Site, and the Monthly Hours, all other column values are the same.

My current idea was to do:

```
for group_name, group_df in df.groupby(by=['UserID','Site']):
    if len(group_df) > 1: # We have rows that need to be summed
        sums = group_df[['May Hours','June Hours','July Hours']].sum()
        # Assign this sum to the first row in the grouped_df
        # Remove all following rows in grouped_df (we already got their sum)
        # Append this to a new dataframe
    else:
        # Append this to a new dataframe
```

While this solution may work, it is definitely not efficient but I am unsure of the best way to flatten the dataframe

Comment: You can do, ```df.groupby(['UserID', 'Site', 'First Name', 'Last Name'], as_index=False).sum()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have situations like this I often pivot and flatten the data frame before. A few key reasons are that it keeps things in a data frame and allows me to work with the index for things like joins. Nothing against `groupby`, though, just prefer `pivot_table`.

```py
df = pd.pivot_table(
    index=df.columns[:4],
    values=df.columns[4:],
    aggfunc=np.sum
)

df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
```